# Terms of expressions with non-commutative multiplication that meet the given criteria

Tags: replacement, symbolic, pattern-matching, hold

There is the following expression:

```
expr=a^3**x**Transpose[x]**y+x+y**Transpose[y]**x**a^3+x**Transpose[y]
```

It is necessary to apply the `Transpose[]` to all terms in which include variable `a^3`.

I tried applying sequence of expressions for given variable `__x^3__`

```
expr /. __x^3___ -> Transpose[__x__]
```

But it seems to me that I chose not quite the right pattern. I ask for help, I will be grateful.

**EDIT:**

Also I try `HoldPattern`:

```
HoldPattern[a^3 ** __] -> Transpose[a^3 ** __]
expr/.%
```

**Desired output:**

```
out=Transpose[a^3**x**Transpose[x]**y+x+Transpose[y**Transpose[y]**x**a^3]+x**Transpose[y]
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `expr /. Power[x_, 3] :> Transpose[x]`? Could you include the output you would like to obtain from your expression `expr`? What "did not please you" in the last result specifically?

Comment: @MarcoB I need to transpose all the terms that are connected to this variable through non-commutative multiplication. See my edit please

Comment: The rule `NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, a^3, y___] :>Transpose[NonCommutativeMultiply[x, a^3, y]]` does the trick?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that `out` was missing a closing bracket and should look like the following:

```
out =
 Transpose[a^3 ** x ** Transpose[x] ** y] +
  x +
  Transpose[y ** Transpose[y] ** x ** a^3] +
  x ** Transpose[y]
```

Here are two pretty similar approaches to achieve that:

```
rule1 = expr /. 
  NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, a^3, y___] :> 
   Transpose[NonCommutativeMultiply[x, a^3, y]];

rule2 = expr /. x_NonCommutativeMultiply?(MemberQ[#, a^3] &) :> Transpose[x];

rule1 == rule2 == out
(* Out: True *)
```

Note that in the above I "hard-coded" the presence of $a^3$ specifically, and not any variable raised to the third power. If you wanted to apply your rule to another variable, then change the `a^3` expression in those rules. If you wanted to apply it to any expression that contains a cube, independent of the name of the variable, then change `a^3` to the pattern `a_^3` in the left-hand sides of the expressions above.

Comment: Hello! Please help me modify your code to transpose terms in such expressions:

`J.a^3 + J.(-P.a^3) /. x_Dot?(MemberQ[#, a^3] &) :> Transpose[x]`

`J.a^3 + J.(-P.a^3) /.x_Dot?(MemberQ[#, (Dot[a___, a^3])] &) :> Transpose[x]`

Problem: `a^3` in the corresponding term can be enclosed in brackets (moreover, the level of brackets can be arbitrary). It is necessary that the program works in the case of a deep level of brackets.

Otherwise, only parts of the terms that are next to $a ^ 3$ and are separated from the rest of the term by brackets are transposed

Comment: @dtn That doesn't seem related to this question, so it would be best if you started a new question with your current problem.

Comment: Well, let's try! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273219/replacing-a-term-according-to-a-given-criterion-in-an-expression-with-non-commut