# Replacing a term according to a given criterion in an expression with non-commutative multiplication (for any sign and location)

Tags: replacement, symbolic, pattern-matching, hold

There is the following expression:

```
expr = a^3 ** x + x ** (a^3 ** 1) + y ** x ** 1 - 
  x ** x ** y ** (-P ** a^3) + y ** (P ** (-a^3 ** M)) - 
  x ** (-M ** (P ** (M ** a^3))) + x ** y ** z

expr /. x_NonCommutativeMultiply?(MemberQ[#, a^3] &) :> Transpose[x]

expr /. NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, a^3, y___] :> Transpose[NonCommutativeMultiply[x, a^3, y]]
```

It is necessary to apply the `Transpose[]` to all terms in which include variable `a^3`.

This issue has been discussed in this thread: [Terms of expressions with non-commutative multiplication that meet the given criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268592/terms-of-expressions-with-non-commutative-multiplication-that-meet-the-given-cri)

The problem is complicated by the number of levels of occurrence of `a^3` more and the code from the previous topic does not work for all terms. It transposes only those parts of the terms that are delimited by brackets from the rest of the term, i.e.:

[image]

**Desired output:**

```
out = Transpose[a^3 ** x] + Transpose[x ** (a^3 ** 1)] + y ** x ** 1 -
   Transpose[x ** x ** y ** (-P ** a^3)] + 
  Transpose[y ** (P ** (-a^3 ** M))] - 
  Transpose[x ** (-M ** (P ** (M ** a^3)))] + x ** y ** z
```

Comment: `expr /. Longest[x_NonCommutativeMultiply]/;!FreeQ[x,a^3]:> Transpose[x]` is this your desired one?

Comment: @lilyric I'm going to try now

Comment: @lilyric Yes it works! Only a little tweak is needed. Is it possible to make it so that only those terms are transposed, where $a ^ 3$ is NOT transposed...

Comment: Could you give an example? You mean escaping the terms like `b**Transpose[a^3]`, like `b**a^3+b**Transpose[a^3]/. Longest[x_NonCommutativeMultiply]/;!FreeQ[x,a^3]&&FreeQ[x,Transpose[a^3]]:> Transpose[x]` returns `b**Transpose[a^3]+Transpose[b**a^3]`?

Comment: @lilyric Example 1: `b ** (-P ** a^3) + b ** Transpose[-P ** a^3]`. Desired output: `Transpose[b ** (-P ** a^3)] + b ** Transpose[-P ** a^3]`

Comment: @lilyric Example 2: `b ** (-P ** J ** a^3) + b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a^3]`. Desired output: `Transpose[b ** (-P ** J ** a^3)] + b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a^3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples

```
b ** (-P ** a^3) + b ** Transpose[-P ** a^3]
b ** (-P ** J ** a^3) + b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a^3]
```

you can try

```
rule1=
Longest[expr_NonCommutativeMultiply]/;
!FreeQ[expr,a^3]:>If[
    Cases[expr,subexpr_Transpose/;!FreeQ[subexpr,a^3],{0,Infinity}]==={},
    Transpose@expr,
    expr
    ];
```

and the results are

```
b ** (-P ** a^3) + b ** Transpose[-P ** a^3]/.rule1
(*b ** Transpose[-P ** a^3] + Transpose[b ** (-P ** a^3)]*)

b ** (-P ** J ** a^3) + b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a^3]/.rule1
(*b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a^3] + Transpose[b ** (-P ** J ** a^3)]*)
```

`Longest[expr_NonCommutativeMultiply]` searches the longest subexpressions `expr` with head `NonCommutativeMultiply`, then `!FreeQ[expr,a^3]` checks if `expr` contains `a^3`.

To escape the `expr`s in which `a^3` has already been wrapped by `Transpose`, we use `Cases` to search subexpressions of `expr` with head `Transpose` containing `a^3`, and depending on the result we choose to `Transpose` or not.

---

### Update 1

```
expr={
Transpose[x+y**a]**J**a,
b ** (-P ** a) + b ** Transpose[-P ** a],
b ** (-P ** J ** a) + b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a]
};
rule1=
Longest[expr_NonCommutativeMultiply]:>If[
    !FreeQ[expr/.{_Transpose:>Null},a],
    Transpose@expr,
    expr
    ];

expr//Column
expr/.rule1//Column
```

[image]

Why use `If` here?

> The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts.

After finding the longest `expr_NonCommutativeMultiply`, we don't want the subparts of which to be matched again.

`/.{_Transpose:>Null}` is to hide the subexprs with head `Transpose`, and then we search if there are `a`
or `a^3` left.

---

### Update 2

```
expr={
b ** a + Transpose[J ** a],
b ** a + Transpose[J]**a,
Transpose[x+y**a]**J**a,
b ** (-P ** a) + b ** Transpose[-P ** a],
b ** (-P ** J ** a) + b ** Transpose[-P ** (-J) ** a]
};
rule1={
expr_Transpose/;!FreeQ[expr,a]:>expr,
Longest[expr_NonCommutativeMultiply]:>If[
    !FreeQ[expr/.{_Transpose:>Null},a],
    Transpose@expr,
    expr]
};

expr//Column
expr/.rule1//Column
```

[image]

The first rule `expr_Transpose/;!FreeQ[expr,a]:>expr,` is to shade the terms like `+Transpose[...,[...,a]]+`.

Comment: Your code seems to work. I modified it a little so that we can work with constants (for example, with `1`), including negative ones. 


`rule = Longest[expr_Dot] /; ! FreeQ[expr, 1] || ! FreeQ[expr, -1] :> 
   If[Cases[expr, 
      subexpr_Transpose /; ! FreeQ[subexpr, 1] || ! 
         FreeQ[expr, -1], {0, Infinity}] === {}, Transpose@expr, 
    expr];`


I will test your version! Thank you It seems to be a very good solution.

Comment: @dtn where is the `a^3`?

Comment: Yes, there myst be `a^3`, `Transpose[x+y**a^3]**J**(a^3)`

Comment: @dtn I see, so you mean if there is at least one `a^3` not wrapped by `Transpose`, then we `Transpose` it?

Comment: Yes, then we tranpose it!

Comment: @dtn I add to the answer with some explanations.

Comment: `expr=b ** (a) + Transpose[J ** a]`

Desired output: `Transpose[b ** (a)] + Transpose[J ** a]`

Out: `Transpose[b ** a] + Transpose[Transpose[J ** a]]`

With this method, all terms in such an expression are transposed.

Comment: @dtn another update. Let's see if there are other cases I haven't considered. I also wonder if there is more elegant method.

Comment: I will carefully work on the code and try to find additional cases. As for a more elegant method, what do you think of the following approach? 

`rule1 = NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, d_?NumericQ b_, c___] :> 
   d NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, c];`

`rule2 = NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, Transpose[d_?NumericQ b_], 
    c___] :> d NonCommutativeMultiply[a, Transpose[b], c];`

`rule3 = x_NonCommutativeMultiply?(MemberQ[#, a^3] &) :> Transpose[x];`

`expr /. rule1 /. rule2 /. rule3;`

Comment: The first two rules open parentheses and move all constants "forward" of the term. The third rule, simply by the presence of $a^3$ in a term, transposes/does not transpose this term.

Comment: @dtn the new rules behave differently away from your previous question. And if this is your true question, then I personally recommend a more systematic way of doing noncommutative algebras: [Virasoro.nb](https://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/Mathematica/index.html)

Comment: @dtn I learnt building noncommutative algebra package from this notebook. Headrick uses `SetDelayed` and it's easy to change to `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: This was not my true question. This arose already in the process of working on the task, simply as a possible option to get rid of the `levelspec` in the terms and use alternative commands